# how should i join these five tables & SUM multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with 5 tables that have related data.. 
it looks something like this..

[image: Database Diagram with 5 tables]

The table "associate_payin_ad" stores the date of registration & annexure id. Physically an Annexure is just a piece of paper which can have zero or more "Payin" or "Associate" entries..
Also 'payin' & 'associate' tables have multiple mode's of payment (like cash, cheque, bdcash, bdcheque) for the [amount] & [payment] column.. there are separate tables present for bycash, bycheque, bybdcash & bybdcheque, I have shown just the 'bycash' tables...
If the tables are filled with the following below given data..

```
[associate_payin_ad] Table:  
adid | date_register | annexure_id  
1 | 05/12/2011 | 1  
2 | 05/12/2011 | 2  
3 | 06/12/2011 | 1  
4 | 07/12/2011 | 1  

[payin] Table:  
fid | amount | adid  
1 | 10000 | 1  [this entry was made on 05/12/2011 in annexure no 1]  
2 | 10000 | 1  [this entry was made on 05/12/2011 in annexure no 1]  
3 | 40000 | 2  [this entry was made on 05/12/2011 in annexure no 2]  
4 | 10000 | 4  [this entry was made on 07/12/2011 in annexure no 1]  

[payin_bycash] Table:  
fid | bycash  
1 |  10000  
2 |  10000  
3 |  40000  
4 |  10000  

[associate] table...  
 aid | payment | adid  
 1 | 200 | 1  [this entry was made on 05/12/2011 in annexure no 1]  
 2 | 200 | 3  [this entry was made on 06/12/2011 in annexure no 1]  

[associate_bycash] table...  
 aid | bycashajf  
 1 | 200  
 2 | 200
```

I need the SUM of [payin_bycash.bycash] & [associate_bycash.bycashajf] for a particular date range.. (for eg. 05/12/2011 to 07/12/2011)

```
date_register | amount  
05/12/2011 | 60200  
06/12/2011 | 200  
07/12/2011 | 10000
```

I have been running around in circles since yesterday trying to figure out the appropriate query.. the best I could come up with it is this, but in vain:

```
SELECT apad.date_register,  
SUM(ISNULL(pica.cash_in_hand, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(aca.bycashajf, 0)) AS amount  
FROM associate_payin_ad AS apad LEFT OUTER JOIN  
payin AS pi ON apad.adid = pi.adid INNER JOIN  
payin_bycash AS pica ON pi.fid = pica.fid  
LEFT OUTER JOIN associate AS asso ON apad.adid = asso.adid INNER JOIN  
associate_bycash AS aca ON asso.aid = aca.aid  
WHERE (apad.date_register BETWEEN @date_initial AND @date_final)  
GROUP BY apad.date_register
```

The above query returns me just this..

```
date_register | amount  
05/12/2011 | 20400
```

What am i doing wrong?

thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix inner and outer joins like that. When you use a left outer join, it will return null records in the right hand table to ensure that all rows from the left hand table are returned as expected. However, if you then try to join the right hand table to another table using an INNER join, the null records will be filtered out as you won't have matching null records in the other table.

In your case, this is happening when you join to payin. You'll get a row for aid=3, but then that row is filtered out when you try to join to payin_bycash, as aid=3 doesn't exist in payin.. Same problem for your join to associate.

The best way to around this problem is to left join to a subquery (or you could do it with a CRE).. Try this:

```
SELECT apad.date_register,  
SUM(ISNULL(pica.cash_in_hand, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(aca.bycashajf, 0)) AS amount  
FROM associate_payin_ad AS apad 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT payin_bycash.cash_in_hand 
  FROM payin 
  INNER JOIN payin_bycash ON payin.fid = payin_bycash.fid  
) pi ON apad.adid = pi.adid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT associate_bycash.bycashajf 
  FROM associate
  INNER JOIN associate_bycash ON associate.aid = associate_bycash.aid  
) asso ON apad.adid = asso.adid 
WHERE (apad.date_register BETWEEN @date_initial AND @date_final)  
GROUP BY apad.date_register
```

Also, have a read of this: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql.aspx

Comment: I executed the query.. Now it returns all the values, except that the amount returned for 05/12/2011 is 60400.. [associate_bycash.bycashajf] amount is getting included more than once..
btw.. thanx.. that was one cool thing that I learned..